# How to build a Flash video player which can receive stream as RTMPDump do

Tags: flash, actionscript, rtmp

I would like to play Flash video from RTMP server. I tried to use flowplayer, but this server needs to handshake with a specific Flash player.

I know RTMPDump can simulate/authenticate a given Flash player by sending some AMF packets, but I don't know if it's possible to make the same result with a regular Flash player.

Is it possible to do that with ActionScript? Thanks.